# How can I clear System.Web.Helpers.WebCache?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

For debugging purposes, I need to clear all of my data out of `System.Web.Helpers.WebCache`. `WebCache` provides a `Remove(key)` method, but no way of identifying all items in the cache itself.

How can I work around this?

Comment: I believe the only option available to you is an IIS reset unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

did some quick research, and found this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1441842.aspx/1

You think you can take Cache.getEnumerator and look through all the keys calling the Remove method?

Comment: That's a different object.  I'm 99% positive it's not possible in the Helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are right, there's no way but recycling your App pool.
I would change the caching approach, say something like `HttpContext.Cache` where you do have an enumerator to clear every cache entry, or any other approach that has not necessarly to exist on the .NET Framework, like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).